# How to keep looping through until user has inputted string of valid length?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program which takes the user input and then checks to see if it is equal to or less than five characters. Then if it meets this condition we store the name, else we keep asking for their name until the condition is met.

I tried doing this using a while loop but I don't know how to incorporate the question of asking their name in. Please see my code below:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static String newName;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        while (name.length() <= 5){
            newName = name;
            break;
        }
       // ELSE PRINT PLEASE INPUT VALID NAME
        System.out.println("Your name is: " + newName);
    }
}
```

Essentially I want ask for the user's name and store it in another variable IF and ONLY IF it is less than or equal to 5 characters. Otherwise I want to loop through and ask them again "Enter your name"

So for example: `Jack` `Smith` are valid but then `Jackson` `Samuel` are not and I literally want to do `System.out.println("Enter your name:");` and repeat the process till they input a name with correct string length

Would be really great if someone could help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: You really need to think about the flow of your code, What will happen when. How do you expect to read the user's input 5 times without actually asking the user for his/her name?

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya Mate read the code properly, I am looking at the user's input length in the while loop

Comment: I gave you a hint on how you can actually solve your issue on your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter your name");
            name = scanner.next();

            if(name.length() <= 5) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would I print "Error please try again" and repeat?

Comment: add an `else` after the `if` and print whatever you need to

Comment: infinity while-true loop is a bad choice in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = "";
do {
   System.out.println("Enter your name:");
   name = scanner.nextLine();
} while (name.size() > 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Main {
    public static String newName = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            if (newName == null) {
               System.out.println("Enter your name (less 6 chars): ");
            } else {
               System.out.println("Error, please try again: ");
            }
            newName = scanner.nextLine();
        } while (newName.length() > 5);

        System.out.println("Your name is: " + newName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would I print "Error please try again" and repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep asking for the name inside the while loop.

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {
    public static String newName;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
  

        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        while (name.length() >= 6){
            System.out.println("Error, try again.");
            System.out.println("Enter your name:");
            name = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        // ELSE PRINT PLEASE INPUT VALID NAME
        System.out.println("Your name is: " + newName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would I print "Error please try again" and repeat?

Comment: under the while loop, ive edited the code